# Debugging an unexpected null in my metatable script

Tags: lua

I've been playing with this metatable and this error is the hardest one to fix:

```lua
local Check = {
    InvitedMembers = {
        John = "Allowed",
        Mary = "Allowed",
        Halley = "Allowed"
    }
}
local Filter = {
    __index = function(t,k)
        for i ,v in pairs(t.InvitedMembers) do
            if i ~= k then
                error("You're not invited by us")
            elseif i == k then
                return "This way"
            end
        end
    end
}
local ConnectFilter = setmetatable(Check,Filter)
print(Check.InvitedMembers.Sans)
```

I tried to make a filter however this code is returning a `nil` value.

Comment: `print(Check.Sans)`

Comment: Please refrain from using quote blocks (with the `>` symbol) in your question unless they are actually quotes (something said by someone/something else). Thank you.

Comment: @halfer I have to use quote blocks because if I don't I won't be able to post a question( I don't know why ;-;)

Comment: Hi @BlaztOne. That does not appear to be true, as the edit above demonstrates. There is sometimes a requirement for code (enforced by the editor) but there is never a requirement for a quote block.

Comment: @halfer Oh ok,  thanks ;>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two errors in your code:

### You're indexing the wrong table

You call `setmetatable` on `Check`, not on `Check.InvitedMembers`. So to fix your code, you would write

```lua
print(Check.Sans)
```

and you'd get an error "You're not invited by us"

### You're throwing an error too soon

In your loop, you either `return` or throw an error, so you will never get past the first iteration.

If you wanted to fix the loop, you'd have to write it like this:

```lua
for i ,v in pairs(t.InvitedMembers) do
  if i == k then
    return "This way"
  end
end
error("You're not invited by us")
```

that is, run through the list and return immediately when the name is found, but don't error until you're done with the entire list.

But a better way to fix this would be to simply do this:

```lua
local Filter = {
    __index = function(t,k)
      if t.InvitedMembers[k] then
        return "This way"
      else
        error("You're not invited by us")
      end
    end
}
```

Since indexing tables with a key they don't have will just return `nil`, so you can easily find out if a key exists within a table.

Comment: thanks a bunch! This is the best answer i have ever seen ;>